# IBM Worklight 6.2. Analytics JNDI properties in WAS ND

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-analytics

About Worklight 6.2 Analytics.

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/t_setting_up_production_cluster.html

There are several JNDI properties to configure but It is not explained how to configure them in WAS ND and in which scope must be configured (if this has sense)

For example the worklight.properties are configured as application properties during the application installation.

How are configured the analytics JNDI properties on WAS?

And also in which scope should them be configured, this is also struggling me. For example it says that properties like "analytics/shards" or "analytics/replicas_per_shard" must be configured in the first node, but for me these properties should be properties configured at cluster level, not at node level.

Also WAS ND topology is something completely dynamic and flexible, what happens if I remove that "first" node?

Comment: Let's be clear here: the JNDI properties are not for the WAS cluster, but for ElasticSearch. ElasticSearch is working under the covers in Worklight Analytics. Each node will get its own ElasticSearch instance.  ElasticSearch has no idea it is in a cluster so the JNDI properties are read into each instance and the shards are split up across the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I understand that when in the Worklight Analytics documentation talk about cluster it is not talking about WAS Cluster but about Elasticsearch cluster.

Taking into account this, configuring a cluster for Analytics does not mean to install the analytics.war in a WAS cluster, it means that you will install analytics.war file in a number of WAS **servers** (not WAS clusters, not WAS nodes) and with the ElasticSearch properties you will configure the ElasticSearch cluster.

Is this correct?

The specific answer to my question is that the value of the properties are set during the detailed installation of the analytics.war file as it is done with the Application Project WAR file, worklightadmin.war or worklightconsole.war.

It is only needed to set those properties if you are configuring Analytics in more than one server.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. When the first node in the 'elasticsearch cluster' is installed, it will read the jndi properties and save them into elasticsearch. Any 'elasticsearch nodes' that join the elasticsearch cluster will automatically receive these properties as well, despite the jndi properties set on the server. There are a couple properties that can only be set once, which is why the properties on the first node are important. This process will likely be refactored in future releases.

Comment: What means "first node" was my next question. Now it is clear also. Thank you.